# nth number of a list of multiples of two numbers

Tags: algorithm

Came across this question in an Amazon hiring challenge a few months back.
Given two numbers `a` and `b` and the list of their multiples in ascending order, find the `n`th multiple.

For example if `a = 4 , b = 6` and `n = 6` then answer is `18`
since the list is  `4 6 8 12 16 18 20 24 28 30....`

Here is the approach I used:

1. Choose the smaller of `a` and `b`. Assign it to small. Assign the other one to big.
2. Generate the list (as shown above) of multiples of both `a` and `b` upto 
   `small*n`, since the required answer couldn't be greater than this.
3. Create a pointer to the last number in this list.
4. Move back this pointer by the number of multiples the bigger number has till `small*n` ( simply retract the pointer by `(small * n)/big`).
5. Move the pointer forward by the number of least common multiples of both `a` and `b` have till `small * n`. This is the required answer.

This approach worked fine on small test cases but TLEd on bigger ones.

Please suggest a lesser time-complex approach. And for some reason, Mathjax ain't working in any of my browsers.

Comment: In your example, I don't see all the multiples of 5? Where are 5 and 10 and 15?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `4 5 8 10 12 15 16 20 24 25 28 ...`?

Comment: @Eric sorry, edited the question

Comment: First thing you need to do is compute the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Reduction_by_the_greatest_common_divisor) of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @user3386109 and if the LCM exceeds small * n, then small * n is the answer, else follow the above procedure ?

Comment: "Mathjax ain't working in any of my browsers" - mathjax is on or off based on the stack site. It is not on for stackoverflow which is why none of your mathjax works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed, find `L=LCM(a,b)`  (here 12)
Also calculate `la = LCM/a, lb = LCM/b`   (here 3,2)
Note that L stands at `F = la + lb - 1`-th  place in the row, and k-th multiple of LCM stands at `k * F`-th place of sequence  (here k*4)
So you can easily find:
-interval where n-th member is:  `idx = n div F`  (here `6 div 4 = 1` starting from 0)
-place in this interval: `p = div mod F` (here `6 mod 4 = 2` starting from 0)

Now you have to find p-th item in the range `0..LCM - 1`. Note that you don't need to build a list (possible approach - binary search)

Answer (score 2):

We can have a simple binary search, considering that the number of multiples up to an arbitrary natural, `n`, is `floor(n / a) + floor(n / b) - floor(n / lcm(a, b))`. Then subtract the result by the smaller of `result mod a` or `result mod b`.

JavaScript code:

```js
function gcd(a,b){
  while (b > 0)
    [a, b] = [b, a % b];

  return a;
}

function lcm(a, b){
  return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}

function countMul(a, b, lcmAB, n){
  return ~~(n / a) + ~~(n / b) - ~~(n / lcmAB);
}

function nthMul(a, b, n){
  let low = Math.min(a,b);
  let high = n * Math.min(a,b);
  let mid = ~~((low + high) / 2);
  let lcmAB = lcm(a, b);
  
  while (countMul(a, b, lcmAB, mid) != n){
    if (countMul(a, b, lcmAB, mid) > n)
      high = mid;
    else
      low = mid;
    
    mid = ~~((low + high) / 2);
  }
  
  return mid - Math.min(mid % a, mid % b);
}

console.log(nthMul(4,6,6));
```